# Docker: intercept outbound traffic and change ip:port to another container

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-compose

First of all, I wanna say that I don't have much experience in advanced networking on Linux.

A have a task to deploy our .deb packages in containers, and applications are mostly tunned for operating on localhost while being designed with the capability of operating onset of server machines (DB, application, client, etc), but since components of the app have been distributed between containers, I need to make it work together. The goal is to do it w/o any pre-setup sequences that change the IP address in configs for components since target IP is uncertain and IP alias in `/etc/hosts` may not solve the problem.

Could I somehow intercept outbound connection to `localhost:5672` and forward it to, we say, `172.18.0.4:5672` with the ability to correctly receive incoming traffic from the resource we forwarded to? Can you give me some examples of the script?